# After moving home directory, ssh configuration is not working

Tags: ssh, authentication, sshd

I moved my home directory from `/home/user` to `/media/newDrive/home/user`.

Everything seems to be working at first, except my ssh configuration. I was able to log into this machine from my laptop with an authorized key.

Certainly nothing changed. However, now I find that I need to provide my password. This is not what I want. I want to use the authorized_keys that is setup.

Much thanks in advance.

Comment: sudo rsync -aXS --exclude='/*/.gvfs' /home/. /media/newDrive/home/.

Comment: sudo diff -r /home /media/home

Comment: check this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Comment: How is `newDrive` formatted? ssh is picky about the `~/.ssh` directory and file permissions, if the filesystem doesn't support *nix-style permission bits it may reject the keys. Regardless, you should run your ssh client in verbose mode `ssh -vvv user@host` to see exactly why it's failing.

Comment: Ntfs is the format

Comment: ntfs is a poor choice for your files and directories in /home as ntfs does not support linux permissions and you run into these sorts of problems. back up your data and format the removable device to ext4 or the linux file system of choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that you may need to check:

1. Ensure that the `/home/user/.ssh` directory has been copied to `/media/newDrive/home/user/.ssh`
2. Ensure that the containing directory, `/media/newDrive/home/user`, has the correct owner/permissions.

`cp -R /home/user/.ssh /media/newDrive/home/user/.ssh
cat /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown $USER.$USER /media/newDrive/home/user
chmod 755 /media/newDrive/home/user`

Comment: After mounting back the `/home` directory after moving, the `/home/user` is missing. What went wrong?